# Backoffice Products catalog Wholesale price column

Tags: php, twig, prestashop-1.7, price

Looking for assistance on Prestashop 1.7. Need to add an additional column to display wholesale_price on the Products catalog page. Seems variable product.wholesale_price doesn't work, as display N/A

I have tried to edit
/src/PrestaShopBundle/Resources/views/Admin/Product/CatalogPage/Lists/products_table.html.twig

and add

```
 <th scope="col" class="text-center" style="width: 9%">
        {{ ps.sortable_column_header("Wholesale price"|trans({}, 'Admin.Catalog.Feature'), 'wholesale_price', orderBy, sortOrder) }}
      </th>
```

and also edited /src/PrestaShopBundle/Resources/views/Admin/Product/CatalogPage/Lists/list.html.twig

and added code

```
<td class="text-center">
        <a href="{{ product.url|default('') }}#tab-step2">{{ product.wholesale_price|default('N/A'|trans({}, 'Admin.Global')) }}</a>
    </td>
```

But not successfully, and cannot get it to work. Attached photo that it shows as N/A
Any suggestion and assistance, please?

[Wholesale_price column in back office products catalog list](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jO5r9.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

The best way is using the `actionAdminProductsListingFieldsModifier` hook.

Check this module on github, maybe helps you
https://github.com/FuenRob/Modules-Prestashop-1.7/tree/master/addcolumninlist

Comment: Thank you very much for reply and sharng. I have tried to install and test your module addcolumnlist, does it should to display manufacturer column already? as currently nothing changed after module installation

Comment: That not my module, I just linked it for reference on how to install it.